# Nonparametric tolerance interval with MASS package

Tags: r, mass

In R, using the `'geyser'` dataset from the `MASS` library, we are building a nonparametric tolerance interval cont. 90% of geyser eruptions w/ 99% CI

Please, find below the equation I am using:

```
no_param_pi <- function(x, conf.level = 0.90) {
  n <- length(x)
  x <- sort(x)
  j <- max(floor((n + 1) * (1 - conf.level) / 2), 1)
  conf.level <- (n + 1 - 2 * j)/(n + 1)
  interval <- c(x[j], x[n + 1 - j])
  attr(interval, "conf.level") <- conf.level
  interval
}
```

Here is the code I am playing with, and in which I am missing something... :

```
library(MASS)
library(tolerance)
head(geyser)

eruptions = subset(geyser, select = waiting:duration, increasing)

nptol.int(eruptions, alpha = 1 - 0.99, P = 0.9)
```

Looking for both

Comment: Hi. Can you provide a sample of your data? You can use function `dput(head(eruptions))`  and copy the output as a code in your Question.

Comment: structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Can you provide an error that you receive after running your code?

Comment: Error in nptol.int(eruptions, alpha = 1 - 0.99, P = 0.9) : It is not meaningful to compute tolerance intervals using vectors of length less than 2!

Comment: I feel that my eruptions is coded incorrectly, but I'm not sure how....Would the original question be helpful?

Comment: Are you interested in tolerance intervals for variable `waiting` or `duration` or both?

Comment: I am looking for both

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these few lines of code:

```
eruptions <- geyser
nptol.int(eruptions$duration, alpha = 1 - 0.99, P = 0.9, side = 1)
nptol.int(eruptions$duration, alpha = 1 - 0.99, P = 0.9, side = 2)
nptol.int(eruptions$waiting, alpha = 1 - 0.99, P = 0.9, side = 1)
nptol.int(eruptions$waiting, alpha = 1 - 0.99, P = 0.9, side = 2)
```

Is this what are you looking for? You have many variations, so I suggest you look documentation under Help. `?nptol.int`

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!